# Array of files not being populated with files from within a directory, can't figure out why

Tags: java, arrays, swing, file

I wish to display the contents of a folder, which gets chosen from a JFileChooser, inside a JList. The only problem is, that the File[] array which is supposed to contain all the files, inside the selected folder, for some reason I'm unable to figure out why... it does not get populated. I've read somewhere online, that .listFiles(); method returns null if it does not identify the targeted path as being a directory...
But I include the jFileChooser.getSelectedFile().isDirectory(); check in the if statement. I don't understand why this is hapenning...

Here's the code:

```
private void jBtnSelectModComActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jBtnSelectModComActionPerformed
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try {
        SIL modificaSIL = SILmag.getSilDupaNume(jFileChooserModCom.getSelectedFile().getName().toString());
        if (jFileChooserModCom.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath().toString().startsWith(siluriNoi)
            && jFileChooserModCom.getSelectedFile().isDirectory()) {
            try {
                jTextFieldNumeModCom.setText(modificaSIL.getNume());
                jTextFieldTipModCom.setText(modificaSIL.getTip());
                jTextAreaDescModCom.setText(modificaSIL.getDescriere());
                String locatie = siluriNoi + "\\" + modificaSIL.toString() + "\\";
                File locatieMapa = new File(locatie);
                File[] arrayFisiere = locatieMapa.listFiles();
                System.out.println(arrayFisiere.toString()); //A check to see if the file array gets populated, but it returns null
                for(File f : arrayFisiere){
                    listaFisiereModCom.add(f.getName());
                }
                arrayFisiereModCom = new String[listaFisiereModCom.size()];
                for(int i = 0; i < listaFisiereModCom.size(); i++){
                    arrayFisiereModCom[i] = listaFisiereModCom.get(i);
                }
                Arrays.sort(arrayFisiereModCom);
                jListModCom.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
                    String[] strings = arrayFisiereModCom;
                    public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
                    public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
                });
                dosarModCom.add(new File(jFileChooserModCom.getSelectedFile().getPath()));
                jFileChooserModCom.rescanCurrentDirectory();
                jFileChooserModCom.revalidate();
            } catch(NullPointerException ex) {
                jLabelAvertismenteModCom.setText("<html><center>Trebuie sa selectezi o comanda!</center></html>");
            }
        } else {
            jLabelAvertismenteModCom.setText("<html><center>Comenzile set pot modifica doar<br> din locatia la care ai access!</center></html>");
         }
    } catch(NullPointerException ex) {
        jLabelAvertismenteModCom.setText("<html><center>Trebuie sa selectezi o comanda!</center></html>");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MeniuTaburi.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}//GEN-LAST:event_jBtnSelectModComActionPerformed
```

And some changes I implement on the JFileChooser:

```
    jFileChooserModCom.setCurrentDirectory(new File(siluriNoi)); //siluriNoi is a String path to a particular directory
    jFileChooserModCom.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
    jFileChooserModCom.setControlButtonsAreShown(false);
    jFileChooserModCom.rescanCurrentDirectory();
    jFileChooserModCom.revalidate();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        && jFileChooserModCom.getSelectedFile().isDirectory()) {
        try {
            jTextFieldNumeModCom.setText(modificaSIL.getNume());
            jTextFieldTipModCom.setText(modificaSIL.getTip());
            jTextAreaDescModCom.setText(modificaSIL.getDescriere());
            String locatie = siluriNoi + "\\" + modificaSIL.toString() + "\\";
            File locatieMapa = new File(locatie);
            File[] arrayFisiere = locatieMapa.listFiles();
```

> I include the jFileChooser.getSelectedFile().isDirectory(); check

Yes, but you never actually use the getSelectedFile().

You use:

```
String locatie = siluriNoi + "\\" + modificaSIL.toString() + "\\";
File locatieMapa = new File(locatie);
File[] arrayFisiere = locatieMapa.listFiles();
```

Your code should be something like:

```
File selectedDirectory = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
System.out.println(selectedDirectory); // to verify the complete file path
File[] listOfFiles = selectedDirector.listFiles();
```